# How to vectorize a dot product of one matrix for every row of another?

Tags: performance, python-2.7, numpy, vectorization, array-broadcasting

If I have a matrix A and I want to get the dot product of A with every row of B.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1.0, 2.0],
              [3.0, 4.0]])

b = np.array([[1.0, 1.0],
              [2.0, 2.0],
              [3.0, 3.0]])
```

If the goal was to do it manually (or in a loop):

```
c = np.array([np.dot(a, b[0])])
c = np.append(c, [np.dot(a, b[1])], axis=0)
c = np.append(c, [np.dot(a, b[2])], axis=0)

print(c)

c = [[  3.   7.]
     [  6.  14.]
     [  9.  21.]]
```

Comment: What is the second column?

Comment: I'm not following the question, second column of what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some transposing and matrix-multiplication using [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) -

```
a.dot(b.T).T
b.dot(a.T)
```

With [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
np.einsum('ij,kj->ki',a,b)
```

With [`np.tensordot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) -

```
np.tensordot(b,a,axes=((1,1)))
```

Runtime test -

```
In [123]: a = np.random.rand(2000, 2000)
     ...: b = np.random.rand(3000, 2000)
     ...: 

In [124]: %timeit a.dot(b.T).T
     ...: %timeit b.dot(a.T)
     ...: %timeit np.einsum('ij,kj->ki',a,b)
     ...: %timeit np.tensordot(b,a,axes=((1,1)))
     ...: 
1 loops, best of 3: 234 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 169 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 7.59 s per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 170 ms per loop
```

Comment: so elegant and simple.  now I'm going to go do this by hand to understand why this works.

Comment: What's the matter with `einsum` on this one?

Comment: @PaulPanzer Just dot products being good at sum-reduction. `einsum` comes into play only when we need to keep one or more axes aligned, not the case here.